# Python - convert list to dict

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, dict-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
l = [('Alice',12),('Bob',10),('Celine',11)]
```

I want to get the following `dict` (as correctly pointed in a comment below, this is not a dict. In reality, I just want a list of dicts):

```
[
    {'name':'Alice','age':12},
    {'name':'Bob','age':10},
    {'name':'Celine','age':11}
]
```

Is there a way I can use `dict comprehension` to achieve this?

Comment: this is not a dict, as you do not have keys in your structure, maybe you meant list of dicts?

Comment: There is a way to use dict-comprehension inside of a list-comprehension, yes, but could you show what you've tried?

Comment: Why do you want multiple dictionaries with `{'name':name, 'age':age}` instead of a single dictionary of `{name:age, name:age...}`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: the resulting structure would go as input to another module which needed the dictionary structure to be what I described above. The other module is not editable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a *list of dictionaries* this way

```
d = [{'name': x[0], 'age': x[1]} for x in l]
```

Your example had a *set/dictionary? of dictionaries* which isn't really possible since dictionaries can't be hashed, and therefore can be used in sets or as dictionary keys.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a list of dictionaries, since each entry has to have a key in order for the whole thing to be a dictionary.

You can make one with a dictionary inside a list comprehension like this:

```
[{'name': name, 'age': age} for name, age in l]
```

Also note that while dictionaries themselves are unordered, this list of dictionaries will preserve the order of the list `l`.

Answer (score 2):

you can make a function to do it

```
def list2dict(list_):
    changed=[{'name':i[0],'age':i[1]} for i in list_]
    return changed
```

then just call

```
l=[('Alice',12) , ('Bob',10) , ('Celine',11)]
d=list2dict(l)
```

Tested in python 3.4.4